# AccessViolationException thrown by OleDbConnection.Open()

Tags: c#, ms-access, access-violation

I am getting a System.AccessViolationException error when trying to use the .Open() method on my OleDbConnection variable. But, confoundingly, it doesn't seem to happen when I run my code on a different computer.

My code is for a service that I want running on a server. It appears to work correctly when I run it on my personal computer, but it throws the AccessViolationException error when I try running it on the server.

Code Versions:

- I am writing in C# using Visual Studios 2019 on Windows 10
- OleDbConnection is from "Assembly System.Data, Version=4.0.0.0"
- ADOX is from "Assembly Interop.ADOX, Version=2.8.0.0", System.Runtime.InteropServices
- ADODB is from "Assembly Interop.ADODB, Version=2.8.0.0", System.Runtime.InteropServices

My code:

```
    internal static bool CreateMDB(MySchemaClass schema, string filePath)
    {
        OleDbConnection conn = null;
        bool status = true;
        string connectionString = string.Format("Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;Data Source={0}", filePath);

        try
        {
            // Setup new file
            catalog.Create(connectionString);
            ((ADODB.Connection)catalog.ActiveConnection).Close();
            conn = new OleDbConnection(connectionString);
            conn.Open(); // <-- Error occurs here

            // Write to new file
            WriteDataToFile(schema, conn);
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            status = false;
        }
        finally
        {
            if (conn != null)
                conn.Close();
        }
        return status;
    }
```

StackTrace:

[image]

The best lead I have found so far is [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27281637/accessviolationexception-thrown-in-strange-situation), but I'm a bit hazy about how to proceed from that starting point.

Comment: What kind of Service project did you create?

Comment: The only case I've seen an AccessViolationException thrown by `OleDbConnection.Open` was a totally corrupted mdb file. My hint here is, your `catalog` object is not freed and maybe the newly created mdb file isn't completely written to disk. Try to create the catalog object in your CreateMDB method, close the ActiveConnection and release `catalog` with Marshal.ReleaseComObject before you open the database with OleDbConnection.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The underwhelming answer to the problem is that my server was lacking some of the files my personal computer had, and only needed the correct files installed.

The missing piece in this case was the Microsoft Access Database Engine 2016 Redistributable, which I ended up finding [here](https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/confirmation.aspx?id=54920). Running that executable on my server got the needed files and everything worked after that.

Answer (score 2):

**To programmatically create an Access database do the following**:

Add reference to `Microsoft ADO Ext. 6.0 for DDL and Security`

- In VS menu, click **Project**
- Select **Add Reference**
- Click **COM**
- Check **Microsoft ADO Ext. 6.0 for DDL and Security**

**CreateAccessDatabase**

```
public static string CreateAccessDatabase(string fullyQualifiedAccessFilename, string dbPassword = "")
{
    string connectionString = String.Format(@"Provider = Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0; Data Source = {0}", fullyQualifiedAccessFilename);

    if (String.IsNullOrEmpty(fullyQualifiedAccessFilename))
    {
        throw new Exception("Error (CreateAccessDatabase) - Database filename is null or empty.");
    }

    if (!String.IsNullOrEmpty(dbPassword))
    {
        connectionString = String.Format(@"Provider = Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0; Data Source = {0};Jet OLEDB:Database Password='{1}'", fullyQualifiedAccessFilename, dbPassword);
    }
    
    //create new instance
    ADOX.Catalog cat = new ADOX.Catalog();

    //create Access database
    cat.Create(connectionString);

    //close connection
    cat.ActiveConnection.Close();

    //release COM object
    System.Runtime.InteropServices.Marshal.ReleaseComObject(cat);
    GC.Collect();

    cat = null;

    return String.Format("Database created '{0}'", fullyQualifiedAccessFilename);
}
```

**Usage**:

```
string result = string.Empty;

SaveFileDialog sfd = new SaveFileDialog();
sfd.Filter = "Access Database 2000-2003 (*.mdb)|*.mdb|Access Database 2007 (*.accdb)|*.accdb";

if (sfd.ShowDialog() == DialogResult.OK)
{
    //create Access database
    result = CreateAccessDatabase(sfd.FileName);
}
```

**To programmatically create a table in an Access database**:

Add using statement:

```
using System.Data.OleDb;
```

**CreateTableProduct**:

```
public static int CreateTableProduct(string fullyQualifiedAccessFilename, string dbPassword = "")
{
    int result = 0;

    string connectionString = String.Format(@"Provider = Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0; Data Source = {0}", fullyQualifiedAccessFilename);

    if (!String.IsNullOrEmpty(dbPassword))
    {
        connectionString = String.Format(@"Provider = Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0; Data Source = {0};Jet OLEDB:Database Password='{1}'", fullyQualifiedAccessFilename, dbPassword);
    }

    string sqlText = string.Empty;
    sqlText = "CREATE TABLE Product ";
    sqlText += "(ID AUTOINCREMENT not null primary key,";
    sqlText += " Name varchar(50) not null,";
    sqlText += " Price currency, Quantity integer);";

    using (OleDbConnection con = new OleDbConnection(connectionString))
    {
        //open connection
        con.Open();

        using (OleDbCommand sqlCmd = new OleDbCommand(sqlText, con))
        {
            //execute command
            result = sqlCmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
        }
    }

    return result;
}
```

**Resources**:

- [ADO Features for each Release](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/ado/guide/ado-history?view=sql-server-ver15)
- [Which Access file format should I use?](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/office/which-access-file-format-should-i-use-012d9ab3-d14c-479e-b617-be66f9070b41)
- [CREATE TABLE statement (Microsoft Access SQL)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/client-developer/access/desktop-database-reference/create-table-statement-microsoft-access-sql)
- [System.Data.OleDb Namespace](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.data.oledb?view=netframework-4.8)